# Android Studio Facebook Login Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook Login on Android, but I get the following Fatal Exception when running the app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.friendlyride.friendlyride/at.friendlyride.friendlyride.LaunchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```

I have used the XML code as instructed on the Facebook Dev page and I'm not able to find the error. This is my code:

```
// I have many more Imports, but I think this is the important one:
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


//---------

public class LaunchFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView textDetails;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        if (profile != null){
            textDetails.setText("Welcome "+profile.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};

public LaunchFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_launch, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}
}
```

And the XML file with the Facebook Login Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".LaunchActivity"
android:background="#953395">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great if someone can help me out, I need this for my final school project :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you recorded the facebook activity and meta-data in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I had, but I looked up another solution that is working now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is work

use `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` 
before

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
```